# Import WEKA model to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, model, weka, bayesian-networks

Does anyone know how to reuse a WEKA model in MATLAB? I've recently created a Bayes Net model in WEKA, and I want to import that model in MATLAB so I can re-create the Bayesian Network in MATLAB.

Someone help please!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Weka in MATLAB by importing weka.jar. Here is a small .m file script showing how to use Weka's BayesNet in MATLAB, written by [Muhammad Shoaib Sehgal](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19260-using-weka-in-matlab/content/WekaInMatlab.m).

```
% Note: You can either set WEKA_HOME as an environment variable or pass
% absolute path of weka.jar to javaaddpath. For example,
% javaaddpath('c:\weka\bin\weka.jar');

javaaddpath('WEKA_HOME/weka.jar');

clear all
clc

import weka.classifiers.Classifier
import weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;

% calling classifier from matlab
v1 = java.lang.String('-t');
%v2 = java.lang.String('D:\Shoaib\BioMANTA\bioManta code\classification\loc_nlboost\bn\loc_trDt.csv');
v2 = java.lang.String('WEKA_HOME\trainData.arff');

v3 = java.lang.String('-T');
v4 = java.lang.String('WEKA_HOME\testDATA.arff');

prm = cat(1,v1,v2,v3,v4);

Evaluation.evaluateModel(javaObject('weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet'),prm);
```

Comment: hmm.. but what about reusing a SVM or bayes net model I've already created in WEKA? Or do I have to recreate it with MATLAB?

Comment: Could you please explain how the code segment above works? Thanks.

Comment: You could either recreate it or you could load your previously trained model using this code: `Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("/some/where/j48.model");` (see http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization). More can be found here: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Frequently+Asked+Questions

Comment: Does this answer your question?